# Limits on downloading map tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I've written a python script to get tiles from, for example, starting here:
http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/1/1/1.jpg

I've read that map servers will, understandably, limit the amount of downloading one can perform, though I haven't run into problems yet. I am interested here in OSM MapQuest, but will also be interested in USGS Topo and Satellite data.
How can discover what the limits are?

Comment: you can create your own tiles with an OSM data https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/

Comment: Just as an FYI, the first tile is actually at `0/0/0.jpg`, not `1/1/1.jpg`

Answer (score 5):

Each tile provider has a different limit on downloading map tiles. MapQuest are currently phasing out their tile providing service and started to use MapBox tiles, so better don't start using their tiles.

There are various lists of free tile providers available:

- https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/
- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles#Servers
- http://mapstyle.petschge.de/

Although being free, each of them has their terms of use, also called tile usage policy.

Alternatively there are also [paid-for tile providers](https://switch2osm.org/providers/) available. And of course you can [set up your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/).